# R reorder bars of ggplot barplot within groups

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, grouping

I have this `data smoking_df`, containing 9 groups of occupations over 4 years (2015/16/17, and over all years) and a respective smoking ratio im interested in:
[data 36 rows long](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OAfdB.png)

I want to create a barplot grouped over the occupations comparing smoking ratios for each year. By setting a specific level order i was able to change the order of the groups (occupations) to be as intended (from HighManagement to NotClassified) instead of alphabetically.

My Problem is: `ggplot` is changing the order of the years within each group to be increasing, i want them to be equal in all groups however, meaning for every groups the first bar is year 2015, the second 2016 and the last all years.

I plot using this command:

```
ggplot(data = smoking_df, aes(x = Occupation, y = Smoking_Ratio, fill = Year))  +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge", colour="black") + scale_fill_brewer()
```

and I receive the following plot:
[image: plot]

Edit: Based on the answer of Gregor Thomas converting the smoking ratio to numeric with

```
smoking_df$Smoking_Ratio = as.numeric(as.character(smoking_df$Smoking_Ratio))
```

did the job.

Comment: Judging by your `y` axis your `Smoking_Ratio` column is a `factor` and it should be numeric. Convert it with `smoking_df$Smoking_Ratio = as.numeric(as.character(smoking_df$Smoking_Ratio))`. As for your `Year`, `smoking_df$Year = factor(smoking_df$Year, levels = sort(unique(smoking_df$Year))` should do it---the default sort should order everything alphabetically, which by happy coincidence is what you want. Your output is surprising, it makes it seem like you've run some custom function to adjust the level order that you haven't shown us (maybe `reorder_within` from the `tidytext` package?).

Comment: If you need more help than that, please make your example reproducible by sharing sample data as copy/pasteable text, not as a picture of a table. The `dput()` command can help with this. Giving us the output of `dput(smoking_df)` or `dput(smoking_df[1:20, ])` for just the first 20 rows would be great.

Comment: And regarding the "some other function"--your data doesn't have any values where `Year` is `"AllYears"` (that you show in the picture), so possibly whatever you're doing to add that to the data/plot is where the problem is. Showing your code for that would help us figure out what's going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?:

```
library(tidyverse)

library(tidyverse)
ggplot(data = smoking_df, aes(x = fct_reorder(Occupation, Smoking_Ratio), y = Smoking_Ratio, fill = factor(Year)))  +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge", colour="black") + scale_fill_brewer()
```

[image]

data:

```
smoking_df <- structure(list(Year = c(2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 
2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 
2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L), Occupation = c("HighManagement", "HighProfession", 
"LowProfession", "Intermediate", "SmallOwnAccount", "Lower", 
"SemiRoutine", "Routine", "NotClassified", "HighManagement", 
"HighProfession", "LowProfession", "Intermediate", "SmallOwnAccount", 
"Lower", "SemiRoutine", "Routine", "NotClassified", "HighManagement", 
"HighProfession", "LowProfession", "Intermediate", "SmallOwnAccount", 
"Lower", "SemiRoutine", "Routine"), Smoking_Ratio = c(0.117, 
0.096, 0.137, 0.165, 0.179, 0.248, 0.288, 0.319, 0.163, 0.105, 
0.082, 0.128, 0.146, 0.174, 0.285, 0.233, 0.303, 0.164, 0.104, 
0.101, 0.131, 0.162, 0.2, 0.25, 0.244, 0.297)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", 
"14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", 
"25", "26"))
```